# Visual C++ 2015 add a reference (WinRT) to only one platform?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to add a Reference to a API in our multiplaform project for WinRT. If I add the reference it conflicts with the other plaforms - Win32 for example.
Is it possible to add a reference and make it invisible to other platforms somehow?

Comment: How exactly does a reference to a WinRT type conflict with the use of some other Win32 API?

Comment: error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "XXXXX API, Version=8.0"

Comment: I don't see a conflict there. Simply looks like you didn't properly set up your build environment.

Comment: There are 6 different platforms in that project that share 99% of the code. I need to add a platform specific implementation of a feature to the WinRT based platform. Microsoft's instructions are: Right click, Add reference, select the SDK extension. That SDK and that extension are specific for just that platform.

Comment: Normally if I have a platform specific .cpp file /or project I can exclude it from building per platform. I don't see a way to exclude that Reference from any other platform build configuration.

Comment: @IInspectable I've been told the solution to my problem. There is no GUI support for conditions for references. Nothing to do with setting up the environment.

Comment: I see, that wasn't really clear from the question as asked. Yes, the MSBuild script supports many features that aren't immediately accessible through a Visual Studio GUI. If you find yourself manually editing project files you might want to consider using a generator (like [CMake](https://cmake.org/)) instead. This has a number of advantages: It's based on text files that are way easier to merge than XML files, supports conditionals for multi-platform projects, and allows you to generate a clean  project file outside the source tree, whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem one needs to manually edit the project and add the necessary conditions to their project files by hand.

For example:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">
  <SDKReference Include="Chat API, Version=8.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I've been told by MS that they do not intend to add GUI support for SDKReferences.